# Clairvoyant job hunting

Tags: knowledge, story

I recently got offered an exciting new position. Not knowing whether I should accept or stay at my current job, I sought the help of Wise Oracle to help me decide.

> O Wise Oracle, why did my predecessor leave the company?
>
> > *Wise Oracle speaks now, prepare if you can;*
> > *The answer you seek is: He was an old man.*
>
> Thank you, o Wise Oracle. What can you tell me about my new co-workers? What are they like?
>
> > *Wise Oracle speaks now, whose words give the willies;*
> > *The answer you seek is: All happy families.*
>
> Thank you, o Wise Oracle. Do you think I have something valuable to offer in the new organization?
>
> > *Wise Oracle speaks, a man long in the tooth;*
> > *The answer you seek is this: It is a truth.*
>
> Thank you, o Wise Oracle. Will I be happy if I accept the new position?
>
> > *Wise Oracle speaks now, while knowingly grinning;*
> > *The answer you seek, it is: In the beginning.*
>
> Thank you, o Wise Oracle. One last question, if I may: What is your name?

Wise Oracle did in fact tell me his real name. Can you guess what it is?

Comment: But did you change jobs?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

These look like

> First lines from classic novels
>
> **He was an old man** who fished alone in a skiff in the Gulf Stream and he had gone eighty-four days now without taking a fish.
> - **Ernest Hemingway**, *The Old Man and The Sea*
>
> **All happy families** are alike; each unhappy family is unhappy in its own way.
> - **Leo Tolstoy**, *Anna Karenina*
>
> **It is a truth** universally acknowledged, that a single man in possession of a good fortune, must be in want of a wife
>  
> - **Jane Austen**, *Pride and Prejudice*
>
> **In the beginning**, sometimes I left messages in the street.
>
> - **David Markson**, *Wittgenstein's Mistress*
>
> *@Bass has suggested in the comment a better-known alternative for the fourth clue and maybe this is what OP intended:*
>
> **In the beginning** God created the heaven and the earth.
> **(Genesis 1:1)**

So the last line that would fit the bill is

> **Call me Ishmael.**
>
> - **Herman Melville**, *Moby Dick*

Comment: such nice explanation, hope 'tis the answer! +1 to both Q and A

Comment: May I suggest [a slightly more famous alternative](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Genesis+1&version=KJV) for the fourth clue?

Comment: An [alternative](https://archive.org/stream/alicesadventures19033gut/19033.txt).

Comment: Nice work! @Bass's alternative is what I had in mind for #4, but your first pick arguably fits even better.

Comment: I'm really confused about the conclusion here. Why *that* book? Seems arbitrary, could you not just pick any book with a name in the first line?

Comment: @Cruncher In principle yes. I just figured that out of the possibilities this one was the best-known by such a margin that no additional clues were needed for people to guess it :)

Comment: come on @jafe, what's the rhyme for it?

Comment: @Grump. Wise Oracle speaks now, he's, umm... wearing chain mail?

Answer (score 8):

Going low-brow with [Chrone](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/78031)'s reasoning:

> > *Wise Oracle speaks now, five years in hell I have been;*
> >  *The answer you seek, it is: My name is Oliver Queen.*